# let's change the slate

Tags: meaning-in-context

i got the meaning of the word  " slate " :

1.a dark grey rock that can be easily divided into thin pieces, or a small, thin piece of this used to cover a roof _ http://dictionary.cambridge.org

but ican't understand it here :

> now let's change the slate and imagine another scenario

_How the power of attention changes everything: Jeff Klein at TEDxGrandRapids

Comment: Metaphorically, something like "starting out with a *clean slate*. But can you add a few sentences before your example? It isn't clear if *slate* refers to a blackboard-like item or a metaphysical renewal.

Answer (score 1):

A *slate* is also another name for a blackboard or chalkboard, [something easily erased](https://ocw.mit.edu/resources/res-18-008-calculus-revisited-complex-variables-differential-equations-and-linear-algebra-fall-2011/res-18-008f11.jpg).